# How to set color code from colors.xml in a vector drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I want to set the color code in vector drawable from colors.xml file of res folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
android:fillColor="@color/colorRated"
```

But it may not work for some low android version device. Thats why usually i use direct xml color.

```
android:fillColor="#9ec8e6"
```

So, finally it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M23.7 12A11.7 11.7 0 0 1 12 23.7 11.7 11.7 0 0 1 0.30000019 12 11.7 11.7 0 0 1 12 0.30000019 11.7 11.7 0 0 1 23.7 12Z"
        android:fillColor="#9ec8e6" />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pro-grammatically,

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(myImageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));
```

or through xml use `fillColor`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/your_color"
    android:pathData="M21,7L9,19L3.5,13.5L4.91,12.09L9,16.17L19.59,5.59L21,7Z" />
```

**Note:** Use hard-coded color(i.e `#000`) instead of, `@color/your_color` as sometimes, they don't work on lower devices.

Comment: In XML `android:src` this works, but not if you try to put `android:fillColor="@color/your_color"` into VectorDrawable and use it in `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes)` expression. It still crashes on Android 10. Maybe this feature is not supported at all?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `android:tint="@color/some_color"` in order to fill the color on vector drawable

Lets assume you have a `ImageView` where you want to use the vector, you can do something like that

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_vector"
    android:tint="@color/some_color"/>
```